# protege DataProperties compare

Tags: owl, protege

I have defined a class named "accelerate", set "Equivalent To" function as follow:
currentSpeed some xds:int [ < minSpeed ]
currentSpeed and minSpeed are DataProperties, and these value are assignmented by instance, 
for example, create instance currentSpeed=25 minSpeed=30, compare them we know, currentSpeed is less than minSpeed, so I want protege can infer accelerate.
however it does not work, please help me.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducable and complete example ontology illustrating the problem you experience. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for details.

Comment: that's not possible with OWL, you don't have variables. And the OWL datatype facet needs indeed a numeric value. You can't state *"IF currentSpeed lower than minSpeed THEN accelarate"* - SWRL is the way to go

Comment: you're welcome. If you got the SWRL rule working, feel free to add it here as an answer. This might help others having the same ontology modeling issue.

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks for your guide, I have solved this problem,  SWRL rule as follow:  car(?c) ^ currentSpeed(?c, ?x) ^ minSpeed(?c, ?y) ^ swrlb: greaterThan(?y, ?x) -> accelerate(?c)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open `protege swrltab`
2. Add rule:

```
  car(?c) ^ currentSpeed(?c, ?x) ^ minSpeed(?c, ?y) ^ swrlb:  greaterThan(?y, ?x) -> accelerate(?c)
```